# .bit domain on Nginx CentOS

Tags: nginx, centos, domain, fqdn

At the moment I'm attempting to add domain.bit as my server_name in Nginx which I've done successfully, however, when forwarding the domain to the server IP or even pinging the domain it's failing to bring up the server IP. Here's my current conf:

```
#
# The default server
#
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name domain.bit;


    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I've been sure to restart Nginx but still no success. There is also no firewall on. When I use my other domain which is a .net is works perfectly. I'm also 100% sure that the .bit domain is pointing correctly to the server domain.

Comment: Start by explaining what you mean by decentralized domain.

Comment: At the moment I'm trying to add a .bit domain to either Apache (as used in the example above), or to Nginx. Whichever is easier.

Comment: Read the [help] and [How to ask better questions on Serverfault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault)

Comment: I've changed the question and made it more specific. Should be fine now.

Comment: Are you sure your DNS is correctly configured ? Your config should work (even though we don't know how the website / php should work), at least you should get something in nginx logs. Have you disabled selinux ? You're doing a fastcgi_pass and I'm pretty sure it's blocked with the enabled selinux default parameters.